# print contents of InputStream to LogCat

Tags: java, android

I have this function here:

```
public void read() {
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            try {
                bytes = iStream.read(buffer);
                //Send what got read to LogCat here
            } catch(IOException e) {
                //TODO: something
            }
        }
```

it reads from a BluetoothSocket InputStream. How can I display what got read to LogCat?

Comment: use `Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(bytes));`

Comment: sending 'hi' prints 16, but at least I know its working lol, better then an error thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of program, you could use LogCat by using `Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(bytes));`

Courtesy `Rundyka Yudhistira`

Answer (score 1):

You can print the whole byte array using:

```
Log.i(TAG,new String(buffer, "UTF-8")); // for UTF-8 encoding
```

You can use encodings from Charset class: [Supported Encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)